# Determine main DLL in IIS vdir

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, iis

Windows server, 2008r2 or newer. Given a directory which is an IIS vdir that contains a .net MVC/WCF application. I'm trying to determine which DLL represents the project from visual studio.

For instance if you have a VS project with namespace Herp.Derp.Web then how does IIS know that it should be looking at Herp.Derp.Web.DLL.

Given vanilla output settings from Visual Studio I'd like to know the namespace name or project name that the vdir came from. I've been looking at the global.asax but in some cases it actually refers to one of the dependencies of my particular projects. Vdir name is not an option as some of this is older and the original setup names where.... bad.

Comment: Virtual directory shouldn't be used to place an web application. Please use sub-application instead. Otherwise, it will always try to load assembly from bin folder of root website.

Answer (score 0):

The Global.asax file in the root of the virtual directory defines which assembly to load the base class from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/2027ewzw(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN